# Linux Wifi: Create virtual wifi card to connect with different source MACs simultaneously to one SSID

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, virtual-wifi

The situation: Hotel Wifi with login-site. 4 devices are allowed. Each device gets 2 MBit/s speed. I have a Raspberry-PI 3 and wondered whether it is possible to connect with 4 different source MACs with one wifi chip. Hotel wifi controller thinks there are 4 different devices and now I have 8 MBit/s which is much better usable.
Of course I must take care about link aggregation but for that on I know how to continue (at least theoretically). E.g. i have my root server with OpenVPN UDP running to connect to.

So is it possible to create multiple virtual wifi adapters to connect to the same Wifi and thus get multiple IP adresse? Can you shorty describe how to or give a link?

Comment: Hi, you might be more likely to get an answer to this at [Unix & Linux Stackexchange](unix.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll ask there. I'm new here, so I don't know what do do with this post. Should I delete here or just link to unix stackexchange?

Comment: I think you can just post another one on U&L